# "Create account" has disappeared from WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I have recently migrated a Woocommerce website from a local server to a live server, so the site can go live. Somewhere a long on the line (I think possibly during the move), I have "lost" my create account input box and button.

It's missing from the my account page, and doesn't appear in the HTML at all by the looks of it. My site is http://tinyurl.com/ov6jw8o
Any help is greatly appreciated

Dan

Comment: the red button on the right takes you to the register screen, but the button does not have any text on it. the element's `value` is not set. also, the google fonts server responds with `400 Bad Request` when your page queries it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that's really helpful. Do you know how to begin to remedy this, and correct the bad request? Any advice or pointers is appreciated.

Comment: I have never heard of Woocommerce before, I just looked at your site, clicked around, and checked the browser's console for errors. I do not know how to make it show text on the button. Perhaps they have templates of some sort? The font is also configured there I suppose. To get the right URL for the font, go to http://www.google.com/fonts, find your font there and grab the right URL and put it into your files.